# Why does Port 9721 intermittently refuse connections on Apache Tomcat 8.5 running on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, connection-refused

**Web Server:** Apache Tomcat 8.5
**Operating System:** Windows Server 2012 R2
**Port:** 9721

We are running a Web server on our internal network and have about 8500 kiosks connecting through our VPN to a Java servlet that is running on this port: `<Server IP Address>`:9721

This Web server was set up by a former employee and we are not sure how it was originally configured.

We noticed recently that about 25% of the connection attempts are being refused (Connection Refused error). We found this information by monitoring Port 9721 using PRTG and this monitoring tool is reporting that this port is refusing connections on multiple occasions within each hour throughout the day. I have not been able to find a pattern to the refused connections...it appears to be intermittent.

Our network administrator says it is not a firewall issue, but I have not ruled out this possibility. We have tried to review the "maxconnections" setting in the Tomcat server.xml configuration file, but cannot find the "maxconnections" attribute included in that configuration file. We do not have the Tomcat Manager Application installed on this server that I can find.

How do I troubleshoot and resolve this port connection issue?

Comment: Hi! I think you should ask this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) instead, as it's not about programming.

Comment: Probably you are filling up the backlog queue. Windows issues RSTs on this condition.

Comment: maybe this is solution to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636527/apache-tomcat-connection-refused-error-while-load-testing-with-1000-users-using

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I moved this question to: https://serverfault.com/questions/1029720/why-does-port-9721-intermittently-refuse-connections-on-apache-tomcat-8-5-runnin